# connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: No module named When running pyz file

Tags: python-3.x, connexion

I installed all dependencies in dist folder
`pip install -r requirements.txt --target dist/`

I created .whl package for pythonapp using below command:
python3 setup.py bdist_wheel

and installed pythonapp-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl package into dist folder, After that created create pyz file from it from following command

`shiv --site-packages dist -e "pythonapp.__main__:main" -o ps.pyz`

When I executed pyz package using python ps.pyz

```
raise ResolverError(msg, sys.exc_info())
connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: \<ResolverError: Cannot resolve operationId "stationdetails.getstationName"! Import error was "No module named 'stationdetails'"\>
```

I tried using different `connexion` resolve like `RelativeResolver`, `RestyResolver`, but nothing seems to work.

I tried remove **init**.py file also, but if I remove **init**.py file, whl package does not include all python files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Directory Structure

```
test
- setup.py
- dist
- pythonapp
  - __init__.py (empty)
  - __main__.py
    \_ openapi.yml
  - stationdetails.py
```

stationdetails.py

```py
import logging

def getstationName():
    pass
```

openapi.yml

```yaml
paths:
  /getstationName:
    get:
      tags:
        - pythonapp
      operationId: stationdetails.getstationName
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
```

```py
import connexion

def main():
    app = connexion.App(__name__)
    app.add_api('openapi.yml')
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",port=8000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

setup.py (outside pythonapp folder)

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

version = '1.0.0'

setup(name='pythonapp',
      version=version,
      description='pythonapp',
      url='',
      author='test',
      author_email='',
      packages=find_packages(),
      data_files=[('pythonapp',
                   ['pythonapp/openapi.yml'])],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shot in the dark, but try changing

```
      operationId: stationdetails.getstationName
```

to

```
      operationId: pythonapp.stationdetails.getstationName
```

When connexion is trying to import `stationdetails` it'd fail because that module is inside `pythonapp`, so adding that to the operationId might fix it.

If the problem persists, please note that .whl and .pyz files are just zip archives, and you can open them to inspect if the `stationdetails.py` was copied successfully and the folder structure is intact.